# Symlink from existing path?

Tags: node.js, python-2.7, symlink, centos5

I'm trying to install an up to date version of Node.js on my Centos5.2 server. As such I need to use an altinstall of python 2.7. I'm told that I need to create a symlink from the default version of python 2.4 to python 2.7 during the installation, and then delete the link afterward to go back to using 2.4.

Python is at `/usr/bin/python`

Python 2.7 is at `/usr/local/bin/python2.7`

To create the link I'm trying to use `ln -s /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python`, which returns `ln: creating symbolic link "python" to "/usr/local/bin/python2.7": File exists`. As far as I can tell, no link is actually being created. `Python -V` returns Python 2.4, and node still has problems installing.

Is there something that I'm doing incorrectly, and is this because the path of the symlink at /usr/bin/python already exists?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339530/change-default-python-version-from-2-4-to-2-6