# Change path on Python without deleting the original one

Tags: python, linux, path

I am using version 2.4.3 of Python. When I use Cassandra's `cqlsh`, it says

```
No appropriate python interpreter found.
```

I think this is because the current Python version is too low.

I downloaded Python version 2.7.8 and installed it. When I type in 'which python', it says:

```
/usr/bin/python
```

My question is, how can I change Python's path to the current one? Since all the members use the original Python, I can not delete the original one.

Comment: I think this [Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256127/two-versions-of-python-on-linux-how-to-make-2-7-the-default) should help

Comment: Have you got `cqlsh` working with the later version of Python?

Comment: Which operating system are you on? On many older linux's like redhat 5.x, changing the default python is disastrous because system utilities are based on 2.4. @SidharthShah has a great reference. Generally, virutalenv is built to handle this type of problem.

Comment: @tdelaney python2.7 and python2.4 should be pretty compatible. Python2.7 will simply have some extra features, which aren't used by the old scripts, so they should still work (probably a bit faster and with less security flaws and bugs). Although there may have been more changes from the C side (not sure when the stable ABI was introduced).

Comment: @Borodin how to cqlsh working with the later version of Python？ What do I need to type? Currently, I just change directory to cassandra/bin, and use ./cqlsh.