# Python version confusion + cairo

Tags: python, linux, cairo

I have python installed in two locations, in os default it's 2.6.6 and in /usr/local/bin/python2.7 has 2.7.

I have installed cairo (cairo-1.12.18) via source using configure/make/make install, but it appears to have installed under python 2.6.6. How do I install it for python2.7?

```
[root@xxxxx ~]# python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Oct 12 2012, 14:23:48)
[GCC 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cairo
>>>
[root@xxxxx ~]# /usr/local/bin/python2.7
Python 2.7.8 (default, Nov 18 2014, 11:15:00)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cairo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cairo
>>>
```

Thank you.

Comment: I just downloaded the `cairo` sources and looked at the build scripts and it appears the Python package is distributed separately in `pycairo`. Are you perhaps talking about configuring the `pycairo` build instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to install it using python 2.7 and not python 2.6 (run make and make install using python 2.7). I assume you use Linux OS so your default Python is 2.7, you can change your default Python but it's not recommended due to several reasons. Please look at this StackOverflow question and answers for more informations:

[Two versions of python on linux. how to make 2.7 the default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256127/two-versions-of-python-on-linux-how-to-make-2-7-the-default)