# Making 2.7.3 default version of python on CentOS 6

Tags: linux, python-2.7, centos

I want to execute python from php and I do have a script that works fine for default python interpreter. I have centos with default python 2.6.6 which is installed at /usr/bin/python and  python 2.7.3 which is installed at /usr/local/bin/python2.7. You can see what is the default python version:

```
[root@me ~]# python -V
Python 2.6.6

[root@me ~]# python2.7 -V
Python 2.7.3
```

How do I make python 2.7.3 default python on my OS. So when i run python -V  i should get 2.7.3?

I know it is bad. The alternative is to uninstall python 2.7.3 and I do not know how to do this.

Comment: 1) This is better at super user. 2) You don't want to do that (lots of things may break.) 3) Take a look at virtualenv

Comment: You can create an alias: `alias python=/path/to/python2.7.3`

Comment: check this similar question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256127/two-versions-of-python-on-linux-how-to-make-2-7-the-default

Comment: where do i type this (alias python=/path/to/python2.7.3) and how do i change it to default?

Comment: You can write it in your shell. Then you can check if it is set by typing `alias`. It will list all the alias you have. To make it permanent, add the line in `~/.bashrc`, so that it is loaded on log in.

Comment: Seconding @OMGtechy's comment. You don't want to do this for the system. The alias is potentially reasonable though but you need to remember that you've done it.

Answer (score 1):

Execute the below commands to make yum work as well as python2.7

```
echo "export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"" >> /etc/profile
source /etc/profile
mv /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python.bak
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.6 1
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/local/bin/python2.7 2
update-alternatives --config python
sed -i "s/python/python2.6/g" /usr/bin/yum
```