# How to set python 3.4 as default over 2.7 in dual installation

Tags: python-3.x

I recently downloaded version 3.4 and installed it but when I go to the command line and type `python -V` I get `Python 2.7.6` How do I set python 3.4 as my default version.

Comment: Read this (replace 2.7 by 3.4 obviously):

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256127/two-versions-of-python-on-linux-how-to-make-2-7-the-default

Comment: It is very platform dependant.

Answer (score 0):

The first step to do is to find where is your python.

You can do it with which or where command (which for unix where for windows). Once you have this information you will know what is actually executed as "python" command. Then you need to change it for windows (i believe) you need to change the PATH variable in such a way that your python 3.4 will be found earlier then 2.6

For the unix you need to either do the same or link it in your package manager.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `python3` to use python 3.4. For example, to know version of Python use:

```
python3 -V
```

This will use python 3.4 to interpret your program or you can use the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) to make it executable. The first line of your program should be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

If you want python3 to be used when you type `python` on the terminal, you can use an alias. To add a new alias, open your `~/.bash_aliases` file using `gedit ~/.bash_aliases` and type the following:

```
alias python=python3
```

and then save and exit and type

```
source ~/.bash_aliases
```

and then you can type

```
python -V
```

to use python3 as your default python interpreter.

Comment: this hardly answers the question

Comment: looks a bit better now but it is not a proper way of doing things, you should manage it either with your package manager (using something like brew link python3) or with path variable.

Comment: it is community wiki, you can add if you want because I tried best to answer I feel doing proper way comes after making it work.