# Install several new versions of Python3.x on an IPython notebook

Tags: python-3.x, kernel, jupyter-notebook, python-3.3

At the moment, when I open an iPython notebook with

```
ipython notebook
```

I can choose which kernel to run, i.e. Python2.7 or the latest version of Julia.

I would like to add a kernel of Python 3.2 and Python3.3 to run. When opening a new notebook, I can select which kernel to use.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to launch IPython with the ability to select whether to use Python 2.7, 3.2, or 3.3.  Please clarify if this is not the case.

If you are on a linux machine, you can create aliases so that `ipython27` launches IPython with python 2.7 and `ipython32` launches IPython with python 3.2, etc.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19256389/4236252

On windows, you can toggle between python versions.  There are numerous options to choose from, just be careful that the option you go with doesn't interfere with your IDLE, etc. or that you properly account for the potential impact some solutions (ie renaming the python.exe) can have.  From there, you can launch the correct instance of IPython.  See: [How to run multiple Python versions on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583367/how-to-run-multiple-python-version-on-windows)

Comment: This is what I wish to do, thanks. I am curious above whether I can manually chose which kernel to use after I use `ipython notebook`. I can do this now with Python 2.7 and Julia. If you wish, I can send a screenshot of what I mean.