# Upgrading python pacakge in python2.7

Tags: python-2.7, pysam

I am new to python. I need to run a python script(riboplot) in python2.7 which requires the package "pysam_0.8.4" to run. In my python2.7, when I checked the version

```
import pysam
pysam.__version__
```

it showed me `'0.7.5'`. But in my python3.4, it is showing `'0.8.4'`. How I can set python2.7 to make use of the `pysam0.8.4` to run the script. Kindly guide me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please try to upgrade pysam module in Python27.

Comment: I did sudo pip install pysam --upgrade and later checked the version, then also it showed me the old version in python2.7. Kindly guide me

Comment: Can you please paste "python -V" output?

Comment: @DineshPundkar Python 3.4.3

Comment: This is basic problem. pip is using python 3.4 and it is updating modules related to python 3.4 and not related to Python 2.7. Please map python to python 2.7 and then try to upgrade it.

Comment: Please check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256127/two-versions-of-python-on-linux-how-to-make-2-7-the-default

Comment: Hi, I did mapped python to version 2.7 and when I tried to upgrade the pysam package, it says "Requirement already up-to-date: pysam in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up..". What shall I do

Comment: Any chance- you can un-install python 3.4?
Just check, latest pysam version for Python 2.7 is 0.9.0