# BASH script look up in /usr/bin

Tags: linux, bash

I have two versions of python installed on my Linux box 2.6 and 2.7, as indicated in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256127/two-versions-of-python-on-linux-how-to-make-2-7-the-default) I have installed python 2.7 in `/usr/local/bin/` and have created alias and updated PATH variable. The 2.6 is installed in /usr/bin/.

After this when I check the python version it displays `2.7.3` on terminal but on the same terminal when I run a bash script (that need to detect the python version) it displays as 2.6.

How should I enforce the bash script to refer to alias or /usr/local/bin for picking the right python version.

Comment: please provide the bash script

Comment: By default it looks like your script is looking at `/usr/bin/python` which has to be a symbolic link. Update that link to point to 2.7 directory and it should be all set.

Comment: I strongly recommend to use [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/)

Comment: @Panch you don't need to make changes in script file. Just set the path like I have shown and then run the script.

Comment: Here is the script                                                                                       `# Validate the python installed
if [[ $(python --version 2>&1) != *2\.7* ]];
then
   echo -e "$COL_RED Qt compile requires Python 2.7 $COL_RESET";
   exit 1
else
   echo "Detected Python version 2.7"
fi`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an alias in your profile. However, aliases do not carried along when running a script.

So what you need to do is to either use the full path everywhere in the script or to indicate the path in the very beginning.

```
#!/bin/bash

PYTHON_PATH=/usr/local/bin
MY_PYTHON=$PYTHON_PATH/python2.7.3
```

And then call it like:

```
$MY_PYTHON ... things
```

Comment: Usually you'll use `virtualenv` for dealing with multiple versions of python.

Comment: @hek2mgl yep! Or even docker. However, in the scope of a script I don't know if it is practical to use so: will the script get to run the Python described by the active virtualenv?

Comment: I would, and did so in the past, `source /path/to/virtualenv_name` on top of the script. Some python based programs, for example uwsgi, even support the path to a virtualenv as a startup option

Comment: @hek2mgl excellent! Then I suggest you to post this idea as an answer.

Comment: Actually it is `source /path/to/virtualenv_name/bin/activate` ... No, it's fine, your answer covers the things behind *this* problem.

Comment: @hek2mgl I appreciate for the hint on `virtualenv` but as of now I would just go ahead with hard coding the path.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your PATH. Then you can use, like this:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Note I am including usr/local/bin before the other path
Include path before it. Include this in ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile so that you don't need to do this every time you open a new shell.

Comment: I had already set my `PATH` and root's .bashrc as you indicated. The following is the echo of my `PATH` `# /usr/local/bin:/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/panch/bin`. Despite that I was running in to that case which I have described in my initial question.

Comment: @Panch What's your distro? I am not able to reproduce that at all.

Comment: I use `rhel 6.7` evaluation version. `The uname -r` gives `2.6.32-573.el6.x86_64`

Comment: @Panch And you run this script from root user? Or normal user?

Comment: I'm running it as a `root` user, and have included the alias in the root's `.bashrc`

Comment: Have you put alias? Or Exactly what I have written?

Comment: Yes I have done that. The content of my .bashrc is                         `alias python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7
alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'
alias vi=vim
alias wkgdir='cd ~/Perforce/t_murup_Panch-Linux_4292/'
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
 . /etc/bashrc
fi
`