# How do I change default Python version from 3.5 to 2.7 in Anaconda

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, centos, anaconda

Without root access, how do I change the default Python from 3.5 to 2.7 for my specific user? Would like to know how to run Python scripts with Python 2 as well.

If I start up Python by running simply `python` then it runs 3.5.2. I have to specifically run `python2` at the terminal prompt to get a version of python2 up.

If I run `which python`, then `/data/apps/anaconda3/bin/python` gets returned and I believe Python 2.7 is under `/usr/bin/python`.

This is on CentOS if that helps clarify anything

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two versions of python on linux. how to make 2.7 the default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256127/two-versions-of-python-on-linux-how-to-make-2-7-the-default)

Comment: python 2.7 is the default on centos. Perhaps you should add an "anacoda" tag to this question because its more of a "why did anaconda mess up my centos" thing. The convention is that "python" is python 2 and "python3" is python 3. I'm not sure why they've messed with that but anything to attract anaconda users to your question would help.

Comment: General questions that would be useful: How did you install anaconda? Did you stick with the defaults or did you change your PATH variable or something? Are you running in a virtualenv when you hit the problem?

Comment: No idea how Anaconda was installed. I'm just another user, so I have no knowledge on the PATH variable and whatnot.

Answer (score 3):

You can add

```
alias python=python2.7
```

to your .bashrc file in home folder

Comment: I don't use anaconda but it seems like they specifically want `python` to be python 3. It may be more appropriate to change the aliases in `/data/apps/anaconda3/bin` or change the order of that directory in your PATH variable. Likely there are other executables in that path that could be problematic.

Comment: I actually want `python` to be python 2

Comment: @simplycoding Then `alias python=python2`

Comment: neat and great answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to change the python interpreter in anaconda from 3.5 to 2.7 for the user, try the command `conda install python=2.7`