# pytest running with another version of python

Tags: python, linux, pytest, pyenv

I've installed `pyenv` and have different versions of python installed with it:

```
$ pyenv versions
  system
  2.7.1
  3.2.5
  3.5.0
  3.5.1
* 3.5.2
```

I use the following command to switch to `python 3.5.2`:

> pyenv shell 3.5.2

And when I check the python version this is what I get:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.5.2
```

But when I run `pytest`, it still runs under `python 2.7.6`:

> pytest -v
>   ==================================================================== test session starts ====================================================================
>   platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.6, pytest-3.0.3, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.4.0 -- /usr/bin/python

Why is `pytest` running under the older version?

Comment: What do `which python` and `which pytest` show? Are the pointed-to files links or some launcher scripts? You may also try `hash -r` to eliminate the case of stale `bash` path cache.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev `which python` => `/home/meysam/.pyenv/shims/python` - `which pytest` => `/usr/local/bin/pytest`

Comment: From the `which` out you learn that `python` uses the python version in your environment, however `pytest` uses the globally available one, that is located under `/usr/local/...`. To run Pytest inside your virtual environment, first install it using `python -m pip install pytest` and then run `python -m pytest`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Bottom line: run

- `python -m pytest`, or
- `py.test-<version>` if your alternative Python and `pytest` are installed with system package manager, or
- if your alternative Python has been installed with `pyenv`, switch with `pyenv` to that version *and* make sure you have `pytest` installed for it. Then you can just run `pytest`.

  - since the `pip` executable is also among the ones being switched, you need to switch to the alternative Python *before installing* `pytest` for it, too.

---

As I can see, `/usr/bin/pytest` (that belongs to the system package manager's `python-pytest` package) has a shebang `!#/usr/bin/python` since it corresponds to the system python's installation.

`pyenv`, [as its `README.md` says](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv#readme), does not replace `/usr/bin/python` - [because it indeed should not be replaced to avoid breaking system packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256127/two-versions-of-python-on-linux-how-to-make-2-7-the-default/19256389#19256389).

Instead, it adds its directory to `PATH` and inserts a launcher there (called "[shim](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv#understanding-shims)") which is what gets invoked when you type "`python`". As you probably guessed, this hack is ignored by a shebang like the above - as it should.

- Running `python -m pytest` will make whichever `python` that launches itself use the package from its installation.
- Alternatively, `pytest` for your other Python version may include versioned executables on the `PATH` named `py.test-<version>` (e.g. `py.test-3` or `py.test-3.6`) depending on the way you installed it.

  - If it's from a system package manager's package for nonstandard python - like `python36-pytest` - this is virtually guaranteed.
  - I checked that if you install a version with `pip`, it only creates an unversioned executable (though you can create a versioned one yourself). Moreover, if you install the same package for a different Python version but with the same `--prefix`, it will overwrite the existing one's executable!
- `pyenv`'s suggested way [seems to be](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv#locating-the-python-installation) to install all `python` versions of interest *and* packages for them under `~/.pyenv/versions`.

  - This is not applicable for the system's Python but the default `/usr/local` can be used for it.
  - Once you switch to an alternative Python version, it claims to create [shims](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv#understanding-shims) for *all* scripts (including `pip`!) that are currently installed *for that version*, so invoking those scripts without a path would run those shims.

    - So, if a package (and thus its script) is not installed for the alternative version but installed for system version, trying to run its executable would "fall through" to `/usr/local` with just the result you're seeing now.

Comment: I don't know why but when I run `python -m pytest` I get this error: `/home/meysam/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/bin/python: No module named pytest`

Comment: @Meysam that means you didn't install `pytest` for _both_ versions of python (you need to do it separately, you know).

Comment: Thanks. I installed it separately and now it works :)

Answer (score 12):

I found [this related question](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv/issues/639). For them it worked with this:

```
python -m pytest tests/my_test.py
```

I hope it works

Comment: I get this error by running the above command: `/home/meysam/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/bin/python: No module named pytest`

Comment: Have you installed pytest successfully?

Comment: Yes, and all of my tests are passed when I run it. But it only runs under `python 2.7.6`.

Comment: Use `python -m pip install pytest` to install pytest in the environment and then try running `python -m pytest`

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to run "black" for Python 2.7, but I have installed it in pyenv's Python 3.7.9. It worked correctly with the script `/usr/local/bin/black27`:

```
PYENV_VERSION=3.7.9 black -t py27 "$@"
```

It didn't work with:

```
pyenv shell 3.7.9
black -t py27 "$@"
```

nor

```
pyenv shell 3.7.9
pyenv exec black -t py27 "$@"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this issue during my recent runs of pytest, and the reason was that I had pytest installed globally too.

The scenario is running `pytest` during your virtual environment is active, and you get errors, the reason is that the shell looks for `pytest` in your `$PATH` environment variable and it finds a `pytest` executable before it finds the one in your virtual environment which is associated with your system-wide Python installation.

In summary to solve this, by running,

```
python -m pytest
```

you tell Python to use `pytest` that is installed in the current Python environment.

By the way, `-m` flag is used to run a library module as a script (Execute module's `__main__.py` file).