# Why does `pip install` seem to change the interpreter line on some machines?

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I put my `colorize.py` package onto `PyPi` and discovered the following strange behavior. If I download the `colorize.py-0.9.1.tar.gz` from the [project page](https://pypi.org/project/colorize.py/0.9.1/#files), and I examine the first line of `colorize.py`, I get the following output:

```
$ wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/91/d8/805853c14a8ccf67ddfe2cf41b634395ef69a1138a0dade303bf4b7c9b45/colorize.py-0.9.1.tar.gz
$ tar xvfz colorize.py-0.9.1.tar.gz
$ head -n1 colorize.py-0.9.1/colorize.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

However, on the same my `Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS` laptop, if I install using `pip`, the first line is has been replaced:

```
$ pip install colorize.py
$ head -n1 $(which colorize.py)
#!/usr/bin/python
```

On the other hand, my friend runs the same installation command on her OS X laptop, and gets the original interpreter line.

What is going on here, and is it possible to force `pip` to not change the interpreter line when performing installation?

Comment: Does setup.py use console entry point? If so, the command line script is generated at install time.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, I'm not sure how to determine that; I didn't do anything specific to make it use the console entry point, but I'm also not sure if it's done automatically. It just calls `setup` from `setuptools`: https://github.com/hq6/Colorize/blob/master/setup.py

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is done deliberately: if you have multiple Python installations, running this file as an executable will always invoke the Python that it was installed for, regardless of your current `PATH`. See [pytest running with another version of python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40718770/pytest-running-with-another-version-of-python) for a case where this makes a difference -- specifically, prevents breakage of system scripts that are Python-based.

[`pip/_vendor/distlib/scripts.py:_make_script()`](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/master/src/pip/_vendor/distlib/scripts.py#L286) is the code that does the job (look for "shebang").

There's absolutely no reason (thus no provided way) to disable this functionality: running a script with a different installation than what it was installed for is practically guaranteed to break it. If you really want it, you can always run `<different python> <path_to_script.py>`. As Python's motto goes: "make right things easy, make wrong things hard".

Comment: Thanks for finding the code that actually does this. :)

Comment: @merlin2011 Just searched `pip`'s dir for "shebang", and the right results came up. A few reference searches later, got the whole picture. Was actually quite easy this time)