# Update python on linux 2.7 to 3.5

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

So I updated python using these instructions:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall
sudo apt-get install libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-devlibsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev
```

then

```
cd ~/Downloads 
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.0/Python-3.5.0.tgz
tar -xvf Python-3.5.0.tgz
cd Python-3.5.0
```

then

```
./configure
sudo make install



python3.5
Python 3.5.0 (default, Oct  3 2015, 03:16:42) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

and it worked but when I closed terminal, and wrote
    python -v
it is still python 2.7 and still getting errors executing code that use v3+ standard libraries

How to make it working as 3.5?

Comment: This page may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256127/two-versions-of-python-on-linux-how-to-make-2-7-the-default

Comment: add alias`alias python='/usr/bin/python3'` to `~/.bashrc`

Comment: Why didn't you just `sudo apt-get install python3.5`?

Comment: @mkrieger1
tried it, when I close terminal and type python -v  it is again 2.7

Comment: Python 3 is installed as the command `python3`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You still have Python 2 installed, and the `python` command is still set up to invoke that version by default.
Try running your scripts like this:

```
python3 yourscriptname.py
```

In /usr/bin/, "python" is actually a symlink to python2.7. If you'd rather not have to type the 3 at the end whenever you use python, change that symlink to point to python3 instead. Then `python` will run Python 3.5 and you can use `python2.7` or just `python2` to run Python 2.7 scripts.

EDIT: Alternatively, you could put `alias python=python3` in your ~/.bashrc file to do the same thing, but without needing root access and for your user account only.

Comment: just write in terminal `alias python=python3` from https://askubuntu.com/questions/320996/how-to-make-python-program-command-execute-python-3

Comment: @BudiMulyo If you add an alias via the terminal like that, it'll only last until you log out. It's probably better to add your alias to something like `~/.bashrc` so that it'll be persistent. Nevertheless, it's a good idea - I'll add it to the answer.

Answer (score 30):

//install python 3.6

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3.6
```

//change default python

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
```

//view default

```
 python -V
```

Comment: Python 3.6 no longer available via ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6 ....

Use "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa"

Answer (score 2):

You might just have destroyed your system python installation by doing

```
sudo make install
```

This installs in the default path! And will possibly overwrite anything your linux distro has there to work correctly.
Never do sudo make installs if you're not sure where the resulting stuff goes.
In case of Python, you should have done

```
sudo make altinstall
```

to have it installed next to the default python but the best thing is to install and use the python version via your distro's package manager.

Answer (score 1):

I read that changing global python to 3.5 can cause some problems
so I set build commands in geany for python3 and I can still run scripts outside by typing python3 xxx.py and it's comfortable now

Answer (score 0):

Python no longer available via ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6
Use "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa"

install python 3.11.3

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3.11
```

change default python (with -f flag, forced)

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.11 /usr/bin/python -f
```

view default

```
 python -V
```

also can update pip packages

```
pip freeze > packages.txt
python3.11 -m pip install -r packages.txt
```