# Getting Error(ImportError: No module named 'PyPDF2') in odoo-11 when starting the server

Tags: xml, python-2.7, server, odoo

I have set up the version 11 of odoo and  when I started my server  it's getting  errors like:

```
ImportError: No module named 'PyPDF2'
```

For that I have already installed the packages but it still generates the error. And I'm working on python-2.7.

Comment: how did you install odoo from github??

Comment: In github there is odoo-11 so i just clone the  module in my system.

Comment: odoo-11 is configured for python 3.5 So may be due to python version confliction your server is not running.

Comment: As you must have already noticed that Ubuntu 16.04 has 'python 2.7.12' by default.So when in stalling the python 3  so there should be  conflict of  python packages.so what to do?

Comment: Remove 2.7 packages and install manually 3.5 packages

Comment: Actually when python 2.7 is remove  may be  it's  craash your system terminal.... so my question is  is it  safe to do it..? means remove 2.7 and install 3.5?

Comment: By means of remove not totally remove.. Upgrade your packages to 2.7 to 3.5

Comment: For updation this links are may be helpful to you:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41839344/update-python-on-linux-2-7-to-3-5

https://superuser.com/questions/241865/updating-python-on-ubuntu-system

Comment: when updating  2.7  to 3.5  it's crash the packages  which already in system. so  is their any other  option where i can simply start my v11 server.??

Comment: can anyone tell me  hot  to resolve the [ ImportError: No module named 'models' ] -ERROR   in version 11  of  odoo...????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone has this error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'PyPDF2'
```

I have got this error  and I have found  this  solution. There is no need to do extra. You just have to write this command for whatever error generate to set a `version 11` environment.

Try this command:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pypdf2.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows

```
run --> cmd --> pip install PyPDF2
```

If you are using Ubuntu server

```
Terminal --> sudo apt-get install PyPDF2
```

Otherwise manually download the package from the given link and install it. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyPDF2/1.25

after installing restart your Odoo application. Hope it works

Comment: Yes i'm working with Ubuntu version-16.04 . and yes i'ev already installing the PyPDF2 packages for  Python Lib but it didn't worked for me.

Comment: please check whether the package is installed properly

Comment: okie for your call i'ev checked again. 
&&  these show  me like - Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyPDF2-1.26.0-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for PyPDF2==1.26.0
Finished processing dependencies for PyPDF2==1.26.0

Comment: Error-Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/home/dipen/v11/odoo/odoo/tools/pdf.py", line 4, in <module>
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
ImportError: No module named 'PyPDF2'

Comment: pip install pdfmerge ?

Comment: One more thing to ask  if  i downlaod this package - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyPDF2/1.25    so  when it's downlaod  so  what's the next  process? either i ahve to replace the packages  or  smthng  wt??

Answer (score 0):

Just download 3.5 packages no need to remove 2.7 packages and after that migrate your custom py files in 3.5 version. So that that all are compatible with 3.5 packages. After that configure your interpreter to 3.5 and run odoo-bin file. I follow this path and currently working in v11 with python 3.5

Answer (score 0):

First install [python version > 3.5](https://www.python.org/downloads/)

Next use `pip` to reinstall all the requirements for Odoo-11. Use the command:

```sh
python3.5 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I am using python3.5 for the example.

Then re-run the odoo server using

```sh
python3.5 odoo-bin --addons=addons/
```

Comment: check the path where you are executing the command. Make sure it is where we can find requirements.txt file. If not you can provide an absolute path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

I made the foolish mistake of not setting correct python environment on my pycharm project: was using globan python instead of local environment, the first not having PyPDF2 installed while the second did. Check your current python environment.