# How to upgrade python version on Ubuntu

Tags: python

I'm using Ubuntu 14.0.4. In my system I have installed Anaconda with python 2.7.14. Now I want to upgrade my python version & would like to use Python 3.6.3. So I followed the steps mentioned in below link

> [Update python on linux 2.7 to 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41839344/update-python-on-linux-2-7-to-3-5)

But after doing this my `python --version` command is showing python 2.7.14. Can you suggest me how to upgrade?

Comment: Have you seen the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50348975/how-to-change-python-version-in-command-prompt-if-i-have-2-python-version-instal/50349150#50349150)? (won't mark as duplicate, because the other question seemed to be about some weird operating system built around so-called "windows" (colored rectangles that aren't good for anything except getting in the way of each other)).

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit tricky with Anaconda.

You need to do this within your Anaconda environment:

```
conda install python=3.6.3
```

Comment: Also with ubuntu they should try python3 --version

Comment: @Ramy, Thank you. How do I access Anaconda environment from ubuntu?