# Installing python from source got the same system python

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ubuntu, compilation

I tried to installed the latest version of Python2.7.13 from source on a completely new VM running Ubuntu 14.04. I just installed the some prerequisites and then download the Python2.7.13 source file from the official website.

Guided by the official doc and some [tutorials](http://tecadmin.net/install-python-2-7-on-ubuntu-and-linuxmint/#) that one can find, I first ran:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local \
            --enable-shared     \
            --with-system-expat \
            --with-system-ffi   \
            --enable-unicode=ucs4
```

followed by `sudo make` and `sudo make altinstall`.

After this, I thought in the folder `/usr/local/bin` there should exist a python executable with the version 2.7.13. However, I find all python-related executable (`python2` and `python2.7`) in that folder has the version 2.7.6 which is just system python version by running

```
/usr/local/bin/python2.7 --version
```

I retried `sudo make install` to reinstall the new version but the outcome is still the same.

Can someone explain what am I doing wrong and how should I do this properly? All I want is compiling my own Python2.7.13 with `--enable_shared` in the folder `/usr/local` without touching the system python.

Comment: this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256127/two-versions-of-python-on-linux-how-to-make-2-7-the-default

Answer (score 0):

add this to the end of your ./configure options:

```
LDFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib
```