# Restart of python script within script with same python version

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, execv

I am running a python program on a server, and on my account on the server I have the python version set in .bashrc file as follows:

```
alias python="python2.7"
```

I have a python script that I would like to be able restart itself.  It works fine locally, but when I restart it on the server, it works once, and then switches to a different version of python. I have the following function:

```
def restartScript(self):
  print("Restarting server")
  print(sys.executable,['python']+sys.argv)
  os.execv(sys.executable,['python']+sys.argv)
```

The first time I try to restart it prints the following:

```
/usr/local/bin/python2.7 ['python', 'server.py']
```

However the second time I run the server, it prints the following:

```
/usr/local/bin/python ['python', 'server.py']
```

This also gives an error, because I am using a module that is installed for /usr/local/bin/python2.7 but isn't installed for /usr/local/bin/python.

Is there an easy way to make sure that the server always restarts with /usr/local/bin/python2.7?  I would like to make it flexible so that someone can use this restart whether they have defined their default version of python in .bashrc or are using a virtual environment.  Also would like it work if they are using python 3 or python 2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two versions of python on linux. how to make 2.7 the default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256127/two-versions-of-python-on-linux-how-to-make-2-7-the-default)

Comment: I would like to make it flexible so that someone can use this restart whether they have defined their default version of python in .bashrc (like I have above) or are using a virtual environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works independent of which python version you are using:

```
os.execv(sys.executable,[sys.executable.split("/")[-1]]+sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I may be misunderstanding something, but I think you just want to pass `'python2.7'` as the first element of your list of arguments instead of `'python'`.  Or if you're not sure what the executable name will be, pass `sys.executable`.

Comment: I would like to make it flexible so that it works if the user is using another version of python as well.  If I change   os.execv(sys.executable,['python']+sys.argv) to   os.execv(sys.executable,[sys.executable]+sys.argv), I still get the same behavior described above.

Comment: Odd.  I just tried locally, and changing to use sys.executable as the first element of the list worked.  It's hard to see how it would even find your /usr/loca/bin/python if you never mention the python executable in execv.

Comment: It works for me locally as well.  I believe this has to do with the fact that os.execv executes in a shell that doesn't use the .bashrc file.

Comment: That last comment is probably true. Your alias (python='python2.7') will only work locally if you've set it in your local .bashrc - There are multiple ways to solve this of course. My move would be to just use `os.execv(sys.executable,['python2.7']+sys.argv)` as that would in most cases work both locally and when executed by another user or server.