# mysql-connector not seeing python2.7

Tags: python, mysql, linux, python-2.7

I'm trying to write a quick script on a server. The default python was 2.6 - I installed 2.7 along side because I needed it for `mysql-connector` I got the program installed and I aliased it as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256127/two-versions-of-python-on-linux-how-to-make-2-7-the-default) so the system defaults to it.

When I try and run `rpm -ivh mysql-connector-python-2.1.6-1.el7.x86_64.rpm`

from the command line to actually install the connector I get:

`warning: mysql-connector-python-2.1.6-1.el7.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 5072e1f5: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
python(abi) = 2.7 is needed by mysql-connector-python-2.1.6-1.el7.x86_64
[root@localhost ~]# key ID 5072e1f5: NOKEY`

If I type `python -V` it returns the 2.7 that I am expecting.

Where did I go wrong??

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check the version of your python-devel package, and install the corresponding package for python-devel for python 2.7 / (python27-devel)

> yum search python | grep -i devel

An alternative it could  be to use the [EPEL repo](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL), from Fedora for your server.

If you enable the EPEL  you can install python 2.7 and the devel headers using yum:

> yum install python27
>
> yum install python27-devel

These packages won't then conflict with the python 2.6 ones.

and then install the mysql-connector package.