# How can i switch python version, that runs by command "python" in UBUNTU 14.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, ubuntu

This morning i wanted to host my Discord Bot, written on Python on my VPS on Ubuntu 14.04 After couple of minutes f#@$ing with Python repos i realized, that i got several Python versions installed on my VPS.

The main one is Python 2.7.12, that is absolutely old and can't launch Discord Bot, cause it needs `pip install Discord`, that is supported only with Python 3 and upper. After couple of minutes I installed Python 3.6.3, that i needed. But when I tried to install Discord for Python it didn't install, because it needs, as I've said, Python 3 and upper version. I saw in cmd, that while installing this Discord Plugin for Python cmd tried to execute command `python setup.py egg_info`, that failed because `python` runs Python 2.7.12 and to run Python 3.6.3 I've installed i need to write `python3.6`. So, how can i switch the default (main) version of Python in order to run Python 3.6.3, while executing `python`.

Thank you for your answers. (My apologize, if I've exploded your brain)

Comment: The easier solution would be to run python 3 using the command `python3`which is the default behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not recommended to change default python. 
You just type 'python3'

```
$ python3 yourscript.py
```

Or take a look at this [Two versions of python on linux. how to make 2.7 the default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256127/two-versions-of-python-on-linux-how-to-make-2-7-the-default)

Answer (score 0):

**Windows**
To run Python2.x

```
py -2 script.py
```

To run Python 3.x

```
py -3 script.py
```

On Linux use :-

```
python3 script.py
```

Comment: Oh that py -2 and py -3 works on Windows. Use python3

Comment: Also **thnx** for help :)