# Default python in terminal won't change despite exports and aliases in ~/.bashrc and ~/.bash_aliases

Tags: python, bash, alias

I have followed instructions in examples like [this](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-change-from-default-to-alternative-python-version-on-debian-linux), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256127/two-versions-of-python-on-linux-how-to-make-2-7-the-default).

I have this line in my ~/.bashrc file

```
export python="/usr/local/bin/python3.6"
```

This lines in my ~/.bash_aliases file

```
alias python='/usr/local/bin/python3.6'
```

This is my PATH variable

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS
```

And I still have the following python version and path

```
User$ which python
/usr/bin/python
User$ python --version
Python 2.7.10
```

I have also already tried exiting the terminal and reopening

Here is what is within the directories /usr/local/bin/python3.6* and /usr/bin/python*

```
User$ /usr/local/bin/python3.6
python3.6          python3.6-config   python3.6m-config  
python3.6-32       python3.6m         
User$ /usr/bin/python
python            python2.6-config  pythonw           
python-config     python2.7         pythonw2.6        
python2.6         python2.7-config  pythonw2.7
```

Thank-you

Comment: it looks like you're using os x? Terminal in OS X uses `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: The `export` line isn't doing you any favors; it's making an environment variable that's never used. The `alias` in `.bash_aliases` should work, however. Are you sure `python3.6` is in that directory? On my system, it's in `/usr/bin/`

Comment: Place the entry you want *first* in your path, not second

Comment: Also, are you sourcing the files you modify?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes I'm sourcing the files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think the problem may be, you started a login shell which looks for `~/.bash_profile`, and `~/.bash_aliases` is not sourced in `~/.bash_profile`. So the `alias` command in `~/.bash_aliases` was never executed. You can check this by invoking `alias python`.**

BTW, export a variable named python is pointless in your case since it 
 will never be used.

Apropos which ~/.bash* files is read, you can reference `man bash` at the `INVOCATION` chapter. Here is some of them.

> When  bash  is  invoked  as  an  interactive  login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the
>   --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file  /etc/profile,  if  that  file
>   exists.  After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in
>   that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.   The
>   --noprofile option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.
>
> When  an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash reads and executes commands
>   from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists.  This may be inhibited by  using  the  --norc  option.   The
>   --rcfile file option will force bash to read and execute commands from file instead of ~/.bashrc.

Comment: Thank-you. That fixed my python version, but not which python my terminal says is being returned. `User$ which python /usr/bin/python User$ python --version Python 3.6.4`

Comment: `which` only print first match by default, with `-a`, it will print all.
In your case, `which -a python` should print 2 matches, the alias and /usr/bin/python.
/usr/local/bin/python3.6 won't match because it's filename is `python3.6`, not `python`

Answer (score 0):

Copy those into your `.bash_profile` file, which is what terminal sessions in OS X look for. Also, as others have mentioned, exporting python as an environment variable will not do anything- the alias should be enough.

Comment: Thank-you. That fixed my python version, but not which python  my terminal says is being returned. 
User$ which python
/usr/bin/python
User$ python --version
Python 3.6.4