# ModuleNotFoundError No module named 'requests'

Tags: python, python-requests

when I am trying to import "requests" in python it shows me ModuleNotFoundError No module named 'requests' error but i have already installed it.

[+] pip list

[out] requests                  2.31.0

i also have two users on system, may it create confusion? i am using win 11
thanks

tried: pip list, checking for env, uninstall, pip show requests, python --version, chatgpt

Comment: You probably have more than one Python environment installed on your machine

Comment: You can use [which command](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/which-command-linux) in Linux or [where command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/where) in Windows to find which pip you are using. Just use `which pip` or `where pip` to find out location of your pip executable. It should match the location of your Python installation for the version that you are using. Also if you are using Python or Anaconda environments that take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50762627).

Comment: This is why it's recommended to use `pip` like this: `<python> -m pip`, where `<python>` is the executable you use to run your code.

Comment: is the module you are using to test requests named requests.py? This way, [the name would get shaded](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-name-shadowing-trap) and hence lead to an import error.

Answer (score -2):

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('mongodb+srv://egip3961:kuYAbaTOX@cluster0.ouoabdi.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=Cluster0')
db = client.dbanime

## Prepare

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36'}
url_target = 'https://www.bilibili.tv/id/anime'

## Request Process

data = requests.get(url_target, headers=headers)

## Parsing Process

soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')

animes = soup.select('#app > div.bstar-web')

for anime in animes:
title = anime.select_one('.bstar-video-card__title').text.strip()
genre = anime.select_one('.bstar-video-card__tags').text.strip()
anime_cover = anime.select_one('.bstar-video-card__img').get('src').split('@')[0]

```
print("Title:", title)
print("Genre:", genre)
print("Cover:", anime_cover)
print()
```

#app > div.bstar-web > div > section > main > div > section > section:nth-child(1) > ul > li:nth-child(1) > div

Comment: ...what does this have to do with the question, which is about the `requests` module not being found?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35822473)