# How to change python 3.5 to python 3.6 env

Tags: python, pip

I have both python 3.5.2 and 3.6.6

```
:~$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux

:~$ python3.6
Python 3.6.6 (default, Jun 28 2018, 04:42:43) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
```

How can make changes, so that, typing python3 itself will be 3.6.6 version. ? can anybody help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256127/two-versions-of-python-on-linux-how-to-make-2-7-the-default - have you viewed this question?

Comment: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-change-from-default-to-alternative-python-version-on-debian-linux

Comment: I recommend using virtualenv to manage the development environment.

Answer (score 2):

Assuing your python executable is located at **/usr/bin/python3.6** You can set a shall alias:

```
alias python3=/usr/bin/python3.6
```

If you want this to **ALWAYS** be the default, you can set it in your ~/.bashrc

```
echo "alias python3=/usr/bin/python3.6" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Alternatively, the better option is to use a virtualenv for each different project, and not temper with the system default python. If you use virtualenvwrapper, you can create a new virtualenv and specify its default python executable by:

```
mkvirtualenv -p <PYTHON_PATH> <VIRTUALENV_NAME>
```

Answer (score 0):

set the `python3` link to the correct executable

depending on where your python link and executable are located (e.g. /usr/bin/)

```
user@linux:/usr/bin$ ll python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 May 23 01:37 python3 -> python3.6*
```

easy way to find the links & executables

```
echo $PATH
```