# Python "command not found" after trying new to move to new python version

Tags: python, linux

I ran the command

```
ln -sf /usr/bin/python2.6 /usr/local/bin/python
```

as in this stack overflow question:
[Change default Python version from 2.4 to 2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339530/change-default-python-version-from-2-4-to-2-6)

Now when typing python on the command line I get "No such file or directory"
How can I make python work normally again?

Follow-up question: I just installed python 2.7.  How can I make this the default python?  I am running Linux.

Comment: Have you checked that there *is* a `/usr/bin/python2.6`? You make 2.7 the default **the same way**, once you've found it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

running the command

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Solved it